xamarin forms ios modal page not appearing
i'm trying to push a modal page, works on android but on iOS it doesn't. Tried running the push on the main thread but still nothing. Also checked the stack and it creates the instances but it doesn't display them.
this is the push
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(navPage);
this is the stack after 5 pushes

i tried downgrading the xamarin forms version but still won't work so i'm pretty much out of ideas, any help please ? :)

Please do not post code as images
